# How to get available area content view xamarin with tabbedpage in navigationpage xamarin form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iub5g.png)

I have a ContentPage in TabbedPage and NavigationPage. How to get height value of green area? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you using `C#` or `C`?

Comment: hi. Please show what you have done so far to get ur task done. Have you done your own research. Homework questions not allowed.

Comment: @machine_1 Im using C#. thanks u

Comment: @minigeek thanks your answer, I get screen height - tabbar height - navbar height but it not working for me. Iphone has UseSafeArea. But I can check all the phones. I need the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The green area is the ContentPage.

You can access its Height and Width property directly.

```
var height = myContentPage.Height;
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I was tried and It always return -1 value. I dont known why.

Comment: The height is establish after the view rendering. IT depends if you need to know the height before it is rendered (for example to add a button that will be the same height of the content view) or after. In the first scenario, you can't! Since code can be running on different screen size, you have to learn how to create responsive layout without knowing the size of the parent : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/

Answer (score 0):

You can add button in ContentPage, then try the following code in Button.click event.

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var height = this.Height;
        Console.WriteLine("the contentpage height is {0}", height);
    }
```